# Trigger Prolific Barcode Scanner device from Android

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my Bad English.
I am using Prolific device to which I need to pass command and read data.I want to read and write data to com port. 
I referred  code given in pl2303driver.jar library that I got with SDK provided here

http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=230&pcid=41.

If I scan something from Bar code scanner I am able to read that data from com port.
If I write some data to device write method returns number of bytes that were written. No problem about that.
But I want to send command to device that will glow light of Bar code scanner and will scan bar code.
I used USB Serial Terminal Lite application.If I give command #55#30#41#AA, USB Serial Terminal Lite triggers Bar code Scanner.
Same thing I want in my application.I tried with #55#30#41#AA, 0x55, 0x30, 0x41, 0xAA commands given in Documentation.But they does not work.
I think I am missing particular command that will trigger bar code scanner. 
I am posting some code here.

```
PL2303Driver mSerial;
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.prolific.pl2303hxdsimpletest.USB_PERMISSION"; 

mSerial = new PL2303Driver((UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE),this,  ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
```

Code for method read:

```
private void readDataFromSerial()
{
    int len;
    byte[] rbuf = new byte[4096];
    StringBuffer sbHex=new StringBuffer();

    Log.d(TAG, "Enter readDataFromSerial");

if(null==mSerial)
    return;        

    if(!mSerial.isConnected()) 
        return;

    len = mSerial.read(rbuf);
    if(len<0) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Fail to bulkTransfer(read data)");
        return;
    }

    if (len > 0)
    {           
           if (SHOW_DEBUG) 
           {
               Log.d(TAG, "read len : " + len);
           }                

           for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
           {                   
                sbHex.append((char) (rbuf[j]&0x000000FF));
           }              
           etRead.setText(sbHex.toString());    
           Toast.makeText(this, "len="+len, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     else 
     {      
         if (SHOW_DEBUG) 
         {
             Log.d(TAG, "read len : 0 ");
         }
         etRead.setText("empty");
         return;
     }

    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Leave readDataFromSerial"); 
}
```

Code of Write method:

```
   private void writeDataToSerial() 
   {

        Log.d(TAG, "Enter writeDataToSerial");

    if(null==mSerial)
        return;

        if(!mSerial.isConnected()) 
            return;

        String strWrite = etWrite.getText().toString(); //  

         if (SHOW_DEBUG) 
          {
            Log.d(TAG, "PL2303Driver Write(" + strWrite.length() + ") : " + strWrite);
         }

        int res = mSerial.write(strWrite.getBytes(), strWrite.length());
    if( res<0 )
         {
        Log.d(TAG, "setup: fail to controlTransfer: "+ res);
        return;
    } 

    Toast.makeText(this, "Write length: "+strWrite.length()+" bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


    if (SHOW_DEBUG) 
    {
             Log.d(TAG, "PL2303Driver Write 2(" + strWrite.length() + ") : " + strWrite);
       }
    Log.d(TAG, "Leave writeDataToSerial");
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OK.I am answering my own question.I was missing command which glows LED of scanner.I managed to get it.In addition following things need to be done:

Baud rate : 9600.

Data Bits : 8

Parity : None

Stop Bit : 1

pl2303driver.jar is really helpful here.